# Jsoup doesn't detect closing </div> tags in the list

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an HTML string with `<div style="position: relative;"> </div>` that contains list of ~200 elements, like this:

```html
 <div style="position: relative;">
    <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;" data-id="0_0_0_0">1. Some Text</div>
    <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;" data-id="0_0_0_0">2. Some Text</div>
    <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;"data-id="0_0_0_0">3. Some Text</div>
    ...
    <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;"data-id="0_0_0_0">200. Some Text</div>
 </div>
```

I do

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html)
```

I expect to get a document with a list, lile this:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <div style="position: relative;">
      <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;" data-id="0_0_0_0">1. Some Text</div>
      <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;" data-id="0_0_0_0">2. Some Text</div>
      <div class="episode-name" style="position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;" data-id="0_0_0_0">3. Some Text</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But Jsoup doesn't recognize closing  tags of list elements and create document with dozens of nested div`s instead of a list, like this:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div style="\&quot;position:" relative;\>
   <div class="\&quot;episode-name\&quot;" style="\&quot;position:" absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\ data-id="\&quot;0_0_0_0\&quot;">1. Some Unicode&lt;\/div&gt; <-- ORIGINAL </div> tag (its recognized like text?)
    <div class="\&quot;episode-name\&quot;" style="\&quot;position:" absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\ data-id="\&quot;0_0_0_0\&quot;">2. Some Unicode&lt;\/div&gt;
     <div class="\&quot;episode-name\&quot;" style="\&quot;position:" absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\ data-id="\&quot;0_0_0_0\&quot;">3. Some Unicode&lt;\/div&gt;
       </div> <-- the same </div> generated by Jsoup in the end of document instead of the item`s end
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This messes up the DOM and makes parsing extremely difficult.
**How can I get jsoup parse this fragment correctly?**

Comment: How do you parse the fragment? How do you use the selector syntax to get the elements of interest? Please complete your question with a minimal reproducible yet complete code.

Comment: Your post can be boiled down to: JSoup is a buggy mess. Is there a `--do-not-be-stupid` switch. JSoup is not a buggy mess and obviously there is no such switch. You are either using the library wrong, or your input isn't what you think it is. These things can happen, the problem is, your question does not include the necessary detail to try it out. Best thing to do is a self contained minimal test case: Write that HTML __by hand__ (to avoid weird unicode shenanigans), write a trivial program that parses it. You'll find your assumptions are incorrect, go from there.

Comment: You're right, the original post was poorly worded, so I rewrote it

Comment: @rzwitserloot I've checked the html dozens of times for last 2 days. Jsoup doesn't recognize closing </div> tags for list items and generates them at the end of the document and corrupt DOM

Comment: In your example, you are not closing the outer `<div>`. If that isn't the case for your actual input, please create a [mcve] and also test that example.

Comment: @NikMAX extraordinary claims demand extraordinary evidence. Show an actual, working example. Given that you're reporting on a bug that makes the entire (rather popular) library utterly unfit for purpose, trust me - it's you, not the 10 year old thing with a million users. If you really want to ask questions and have readers take on faith JSoup is utterly broken, then __include a self contained test case__ so that any doubter can __trivially__ run it. You haven't done so. I shall continue to believe you are just not using the tool correctly / have weird HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to compose the string manually and passing it to jsoup I've found the root of the problem.
In the html string that the network request returns to me, I have a normal opening `<div>` tags, but escaped closing `</div>` tags in the list items. List items contains `<\/div>` instead of `</div>`.
List items looks like this:

```html
<div class=\"episode-name\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\" data-id=\"0_0_0_0\">1. Text<\/div> <--ESCAPED TAG
```

instead of this:

```html
<div class=\"episode-name\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\" data-id=\"0_0_0_0\">1. Text</div> <-- NORMAL TAG
```

So Jsoup interprets those escaped closing tags like text and generete incorrect DOM structure.

**SOLUTION**:
Adding a tag escape check before passing html to jsoup and replacing escaped tags with unescaped ones solved the problem. In my example I just use

```
html=html.replaceAll("<\\/div>", "</div>")
document = Jsoup.parse(html)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have no problems parsing that fragment using Jsoup 1.16.1. You should include the relevant part of your code if something is not working for you

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String html = " <div style=\"position: relative;\">\n"
                      + "    <div class=\"episode-name\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\" data-id=\"0_0_0_0\">1. Some Text</div>\n"
                      + "    <div class=\"episode-name\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\" data-id=\"0_0_0_0\">2. Some Text</div>\n"
                      + "    <div class=\"episode-name\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\"data-id=\"0_0_0_0\">3. Some Text</div>\n"
                      + " </div>";

        Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);

        System.out.println(document.selectFirst("div.episode-name").text());
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried to compose the string manually and passing it to jsoup I've found the root of the problem, I think. In the html string that the network request returns to me, I have a normal opening `<div>` tags, but escaped closing `</div>` tags in the list items. List items contains `<\/div>` instead of `</div>`. Like this: `<div class=\"episode-name\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 5px;left: 10px;font-size: 30px;\" data-id=\"0_0_0_0\">1. \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0445\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0456 \u0440\u0435\u0447\u0456<\/div>`. Jsoup interprets those escaped closing tags like text.

Comment: When I do `html=html.replaceAll("<\\/div>", "</div>")` problem has been solved. Thanks for tip-off